# Creating a dynamic Breadcrumb in Vue.js in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm currently trying to create a Breadcrumb-Component in Vue.js 3. I googled this issue for hours but I just can't seem to find a working solution for me, they're either not dynamic enough or won't work for me because they're to old. I'm pretty new to frontend-development in general so I don't have the best knowledge on what library to use or if there is any function Vue offers me to help me with my issue, right now I'm using Vue3 and pinia.

Here is my current (not final) solution:

*Breadcrumb.vue*

```js
<template>
    <div id="breadcrumb">
        <ul class="breadcrumb-wrapper">
            <li v-for="(breadcrumb, index) in breadcrumbList" :key="index" @click="navigate(index)"
                :class="{ 'linked': !!breadcrumb.link }">
                {{ breadcrumb.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Breadcrumb',
    data() {
        return {
            breadcrumbList: []
        }
    },
    mounted() { this.updateList() },
    watch: { '$route'() { this.updateList() } },
    methods: {
        navigate(route) {
            if (this.breadcrumbList[route].link) this.$router.push(this.breadcrumbList[route].link)
        },
        updateList() { this.breadcrumbList = this.$route.meta.breadcrumb }
    }
}
</script>
```

and use these kind of entries in my router:

*router.js*

```js
{
  path: "/building/:slug-:id",
  name: "building-detail",
  component: BuildingDetail,
  meta: {
    breadcrumb: [
      { name: 'buildings', link: 'buildings' },
      { name: 'campus-detail', link: 'campus-detail' },
      { name: 'buildings-detail' }
    ]
  }
},
```

Here I need to find a way to dynamically update the name as well as the link to match different pages.

This would work I think but somehow this feels "wrong"? There has to be a solution where I can dynamically "store" some data I need as well as the url and pass them to the next page. I feel like there's some curcial thing I'm missing and this should not be that hard to implement but I can't seem to find it.

Did anyone implement something like this and can help me out here?

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. Does it work? If yes then what exactly is the problem? If no. What doesn't. Where do you get the meta:breadcrumb object from?

Answer (score 0):

Your Breadcrumb.vue file will look like

```js
<template>
  <nav class="breadcrumb">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(crumb, index) in breadcrumbs" :key="index">
        <router-link :to="crumb.to">{{ crumb.label }}</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    breadcrumbs() {
      const route = this.$route;
      const matchedRoutes = route.matched;

      return matchedRoutes.map((routeItem) => ({
        label: routeItem.meta.breadcrumb || routeItem.name,
        to: this.getRoutePath(route, routeItem),
      }));
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getRoutePath(route, routeItem) {
      const matchedSegments = route.matched.slice(0, route.matched.indexOf(routeItem) + 1);
      return matchedSegments.map((segment) => segment.path).join('/');
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Add your breadcrumb styling here */
</style>
```

Your Router.js Object will look like

```js
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home,
        meta: {
          breadcrumb: 'My Home', // Custom breadcrumb label
        },
      },
```

Comment: Well yes but I can't just use one value for every entry. I need to set the name (the word that show's up in my frontend) dynmaically based on the view i'm on, I don't want to use a generic name like "building" I'd like to use the actual name of the building. Did I do something wrong here and this should work like I want to?

Comment: Here from the url route it will be taking the things i guess and we are adding the meta tag in router.js which will be displayed.